# How do I install the relevant C++ library to avoid the linker command failing?

Tags: c++, x86-64, linker-errors, macos-catalina, undefined-symbol

I recently tried to compile a C++ program, but found that it gave this error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "std::__1::locale::use_facet(std::__1::locale::id&) const", referenced from:
      std::__1::ctype<char> const& std::__1::use_facet<std::__1::ctype<char> >(std::__1::locale const&) in test-c64d7d.o
  "std::__1::ios_base::getloc() const", referenced from:
      std::__1::basic_ios<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >::widen(char) const in test-c64d7d.o
  "std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >::__init(unsigned long, char)", referenced from:
      std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >::basic_string(unsigned long, char) in test-c64d7d.o
  "std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >::~basic_string()", referenced from:
      std::__1::ostreambuf_iterator<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> > std::__1::__pad_and_output<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >(std::__1::ostreambuf_iterator<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >, char const*, char const*, char const*, std::__1::ios_base&, char) in test-c64d7d.o
  "std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >::sentry::sentry(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&)", referenced from:
      std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >& std::__1::__put_character_sequence<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, char const*, unsigned long) in test-c64d7d.o
  "std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >::sentry::~sentry()", referenced from:
      std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >& std::__1::__put_character_sequence<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, char const*, unsigned long) in test-c64d7d.o
  "std::__1::cout", referenced from:
      _main in test-c64d7d.o
  "std::__1::ctype<char>::id", referenced from:
      std::__1::ctype<char> const& std::__1::use_facet<std::__1::ctype<char> >(std::__1::locale const&) in test-c64d7d.o
  "std::__1::locale::~locale()", referenced from:
      std::__1::basic_ios<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >::widen(char) const in test-c64d7d.o
  "std::__1::ios_base::__set_badbit_and_consider_rethrow()", referenced from:
      std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >& std::__1::__put_character_sequence<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, char const*, unsigned long) in test-c64d7d.o
  "std::__1::ios_base::clear(unsigned int)", referenced from:
      std::__1::ios_base::setstate(unsigned int) in test-c64d7d.o
  "std::terminate()", referenced from:
      ___clang_call_terminate in test-c64d7d.o
  "___cxa_begin_catch", referenced from:
      std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >& std::__1::__put_character_sequence<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, char const*, unsigned long) in test-c64d7d.o
      ___clang_call_terminate in test-c64d7d.o
  "___cxa_call_unexpected", referenced from:
      std::__1::ostreambuf_iterator<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >::ostreambuf_iterator(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&) in test-c64d7d.o
  "___cxa_end_catch", referenced from:
      std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >& std::__1::__put_character_sequence<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, char const*, unsigned long) in test-c64d7d.o
  "___gxx_personality_v0", referenced from:
      std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >& std::__1::__put_character_sequence<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, char const*, unsigned long) in test-c64d7d.o
      std::__1::ostreambuf_iterator<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> > std::__1::__pad_and_output<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >(std::__1::ostreambuf_iterator<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >, char const*, char const*, char const*, std::__1::ios_base&, char) in test-c64d7d.o
      std::__1::ostreambuf_iterator<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >::ostreambuf_iterator(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&) in test-c64d7d.o
      std::__1::basic_ios<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >::widen(char) const in test-c64d7d.o
      Dwarf Exception Unwind Info (__eh_frame) in test-c64d7d.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
```

The problem only arises when I use functions that follow std::

```
#include<iostream>
int main()
{
    std::cout<<"hello\n";
}
```

However, there is no error when I write regular C style programs.

Is this because some library is missing or in a different path? If so, how do I add it?

Answer (score 5):

Welcome to Stack Overflow!

The problem is your using the wrong compiler. Use the C++ compiler  called `g++`, not `gcc`. Using the one I mentioned will set up the linker to link to C++ libraries.

You're able to write in C because you are using the `gcc` or `cc` compiler.

Running `gcc foo.cpp` will compile it as C++ source (because of the filename), but still *link* with only C libraries.  `g++ foo.cpp` will compile as C++ and also link with C++ libraries that define iostream functions.